# Python Selenium: get element by class and convert to text

Tags: python, selenium, text

I am having trouble getting the text element ("1,028 Sales") from the following page:  https://www.etsy.com/shop/susansimonini?ref=l2-shopheader-name.

I can get the element itself with no issue using this:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('shop-sales')
```

But I cannot convert it to text.  The following results in a blank line:

```
sales=driver.find_element_by_class_name('shop-sales').text
print sales
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for your help.

josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.text` returns an empty string because the targeted element is hidden.
So you can either target the visible one holding the sales count :

```
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".shop-info .shop-location + span").text
```

Or you could directly get the `innerHTML` or `textContent` property :

```
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".shop-sales").get_attribute("textContent")
text = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".shop-sales").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```